# Using ".." with for loop

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-playground

There is a code snippet in the swift book provided by Apple. I typed it in xcode playground but it shows "Operator is not a known binary operator" and "Use of unresolved identifier" errors. The code is:

[image: Xcode Playground code]
According to the book, ".." operator can be used with for loop to make a range that omits its upper value. But it displays error. Changing ".." to "..." operator seems to fix the error. But why does not ".." work?

Comment: You need the latest version of the book. The version you have is fort a beta version of Swift.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have an out of date version of the swift book.

Here you go. The current version of the half-closed range is `0..<3` not `0..3` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Comment: One more thing, are these types of issues going to appear more? Will they constantly change the syntax of swift if they feel like it?

Comment: Well in the latest version (1.1) they added the ability to have optional returns from init. That was a breaking bug and needed code changes to fix it. In answer to your question, probably, yes. Swift is still a very young language. The changes between your code and the current version were done before it was version 1.0 and so was expected. There will be fewer changes from now on but that's not to say that nothing will change.

Comment: I was reading an old version of swift ibook and even Xcode was 6.0.1. I have updated both. Thanks for the info and quick response Fogmeister.

Comment: It's worth noting that `...` fixed the error, but it's an inclusive range operator, contrasted with `..<` which is excluse. For example, `0..<3` yields 0,1,2 where `0...3` will yield 0,1,2,3. Use of either will depend on your needed logic.

Comment: @KiranThapa: Absolutely. Forget about learning something once and then resting on your laurels. It's a permanent process. I've got a 1985 book about C++ written by Stroustroup himself, and in the next edition he tells you to throw it away because it's dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Things are now different in Swift 2. Here's how to do it now in Xcode 7 (the original question shows highly in a google search for this particular problem):

```
for i in 1 ..< Process.argc {
    let index = Int(i);

    if let arg = String.fromCString(Process.unsafeArgv[index]) {
        switch arg {
        case "-whatever":
            // do something

        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, sorry. I originally came here for the ".." problem but I was also trying to process command-line arguments. My posted solution obviously contains more than necessary, but I suppose it can't hurt.